# Как проверить не содержит ли массив объект?

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, объекты

У меня есть массив объектов который динамически получает данные от сервера и каждый раз записывает в state. INCLUDES не работает!

```js
.then( ({data}) => {
          this.setState({
            columns: [
              ...this.state.columns,
              data
            ]
          })
        })
```

```js
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 61, name: "Ожидает отправки", type: 0, action: {…}, cards: Array(5), …}
1: {id: 63, name: "Ошибка отправки", type: 2, action: {…}, cards: Array(0), …}
2: {id: 62, name: "Отправлено", type: 3, action: {…}, cards: Array(0), …}
3: {id: 61, name: "Ожидает отправки", type: 0, action: {…}, cards: Array(5), …}
4: {id: 62, name: "Отправлено", type: 3, action: {…}, cards: Array(0), …}
5: {id: 63, name: "Ошибка отправки", type: 2, action: {…}, cards: Array(0), …}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mass.forEach(function(el){
   if (el === "")
   {
   //some code
   }
});
```